# How to exclude zero entry from a dynamic formula (SUBTOTAL + SUMPRODUCT) in excel

Tags: excel, dynamic, excel-formula

I'm working on a formula to get the standard deviation. It has been working not until I encountered a zero value which makes the result into **#DIV/0!**.

This is the screenshot of the expected value.

[image]

However, when I used my formula, the Game Time SD returned **0**.

How do I exclude it in the calculation if the value in F column is zero? I tried **IF(F5:F9 <> 0)** but it won't work.

[image]

This is the formula I used.

1. F3 = IFERROR(SUBTOTAL(1,F5:F9),0)
2. G3 = IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(F5:F9,ROW(F5:F9)-MIN(ROW(F5:F9)),,1))*(G5:G9*F5:F9))/SUBTOTAL(9,F5:F9),0)
3. H3 = IFERROR(((SUBTOTAL(9,F5:F9)*(SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(F5:F9,ROW(F5:F9)-MIN(ROW(F5:F9)),,1)) *
   **((H5:H9^2*F5:F9*(F5:F9-1)+(G5:G9*F5:F9)^2)/*F5:F9*)))**-(SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(G5:G9,ROW(G5:G9)-MIN(ROW(G5:G9)),,1)),SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(F5:F9,ROW(F5:F9)-MIN(ROW(F5:F9)),,1))))^2)/(SUBTOTAL(9,F5:F9)*(SUBTOTAL(9,F5:F9)-1)))^(1/2),0)

I know the problem is somewhere in **F5:F9**, since the divisor used is **zero**

Comment: You need to identify which part of your `H3` formula causes the division by zero. It's too complicated to debug as a whole. You can debug it by splitting in parts and putting each part in a different cell. Once you identify that `#DIV/0` part, you can formulate what you want to replace that part in the case of error.

Comment: @A.S.H hi again, thanks for the tip, I somehow manage to figure out where the problem is in _H3_ formula, it should be the text in bold. I'll post my answer if solve it myself. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part you suspected in the code involves dividing by a denominator that happens to be a *factor* in the numerator. You can avoid a division by zero by simplifying that fraction.

> ```
> ((H5:H9^2*F5:F9*(F5:F9-1)+(G5:G9*F5:F9)^2)/F5:F9)))
> ```

can be reduced to

```
(H5:H9^2*(F5:F9-1) + (G5:G9^2*F5:F9))
```

Resulting in the formula (3rd line modified)

```
=IFERROR(((SUBTOTAL(9,F5:F9)*
(SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(F5:F9,ROW(F5:F9)-MIN(ROW(F5:F9)),,1))*
(H5:H9^2*(F5:F9-1) + (G5:G9^2*F5:F9))))-
(SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(G5:G9,ROW(G5:G9)-
MIN(ROW(G5:G9)),,1)),SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(F5:F9,ROW(F5:F9)-
MIN(ROW(F5:F9)),,1))))^2)/(SUBTOTAL(9,F5:F9)*
(SUBTOTAL(9,F5:F9)-1)))^(1/2), 0)
```

In my tests without the enclosing `IFERROR,` I could set some rows to zero and get values. Only when the square rooted subtotal was negative (which logically should not happen) was the result `#NUM`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I managed to resolved it by using IFERROR to the part where it failed and entered it as formula array.

Comment: Again, your solution is much much better, I haven't thought of that. It seems I have a lot of simplifying to do. Thanks for enlightening me!

Comment: @quinekxi yeah, it's better to simplify all fractions. Glad to help :)

Comment: sorry but can you please explain why _(G5:G9*F5:F9)^2_ won't work?

Comment: It "works" but if will yield a different result. We eliminated the denominator `F5:F9` so we divide each term of the numerator by `F5:F9` so the above term becomes `(G5:G9^2*F5:F9)`